# Bootstrap header image overlaps the bottom border of the header?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

so this is probably pretty simple, but it's stumping the hell out of me.

Basically I have a bootstrap modal and I want the header to have a title along with an image on the right.  I can't get the image to move up a little bit so that the whole border is visible.

Here is the code for the header, and an image of what I'm getting.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button id="btnCloseModal" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <img src="../images/MyEKC_Final.jpg" width="95" height="34" class="top-align" style="float: right;" />
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modalTitleHeader">Getting Started with MyEKC</h3>
</div>
```

[image: Modal]

If you look at the top right, the image is overlapping the border.  Ideally I'd like for the logo to be up higher so it's even with the header, but if that's not possible if I can just move the border down too that would be okay.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The only CSS being used are the close and modal-title classes which are part of bootstrap.  I just used inline styling to float the image right

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle for above issue.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, using this [boostrap fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/5UW5FxMIsC)

Comment: Interesting, I created a test in jsfiddle too and it worked with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxcnjova/).  The main css is a massive file, does anyone have any hints on how I can ignore styles from the main stylesheet to see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Nevermind I was able to get it using chrome tools, something was giving it padding on the top pushing it down.  I'll override it with another class.  Thanks for your comments!